# PHP Authenticate Playstation Network

Tags: php, curl

Summary of what im trying to accomplish: I play motorstorm on PS3 and for the first game Monument Valley, the leaderboards are not available on the ms website. which means i cant scrape leaderboard data. Now i wiresharked my ps3 and i saw the request that monument valley uses to get the leaderboard data. now i replicated the request header in php curl but it keeps giving me access denied.

Is there any resource out there that you know of that could help me authenticate myself as a ps3 on PSN?

Comment: How very hacky of you sir! I suspect your PlayStation Online account is part of the request process. I'm eager to see what you find out here!

Comment: i suspect as much aswell. i got a psn auth class i wrote somewhere... but that is just for the website. it seems the ps3 does some crypto to connect. but just to log in to psn via ps3... it has about 100+ packets >.<

Comment: Make sure you replicate *all* headers (including the URL, some headers may contain a checksum of the URL), do it from the same IP (should be OK if you're behind the same NAT as your PS3), and do it very quickly after the PS3 itself (they may use sessions with a short timeout). If even that doesn't work there's probably some one-time tokens being used, which requires another level of hacking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the request through SSL? I know that in the Wii if you want to do a man in the middle attack of the Wii Shop you need to crack the SSL cert so that the Wii thinks that you are the Nintendo Server. Might have to do that with the PS3

Comment: Since he can read the request (I assume HTTP) headers, it can't be SSL/HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

hmm.. useragent may be an option